# Getting contract block on create

Tags: solidity

How do I obtain the contract block on deploy and store it?

In my `constructor` I added `firstBlock = block.number`, but when I view the emitter, and call other couple of other functions to execute, the first block number changes to current block number. How/where do I store globally the first block on contract deployment?

it needs to be within the contract.

Comment: simply by `constructor() {
        blockNb = block.number;
    }` then your getter should returns "blockNb" and not "block.number"

Comment: How is `firstBlock` defined? If it is initialized once in the constructor it should remain constant. You could declare it as immutable.